# TypeError and AssertionError after upgrade to Django 2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm tasked with upgrading a Django REST framework project from Django 1.8 to Django 2.x. I already ported the whole code from python 2.7 to python 3.7 and from Django 1.8 to 2.0.13. I'm using virtual envs.

I got it running on python 3.7 and Django 2.0.13, and RESTframework 3.11, although I ran into problems while trying to create new objects.

Here's the Traceback to my problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Envs\projpy3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Envs\projpy3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Envs\projpy3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Envs\projpy3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 18, in create
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 219, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 418, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 471, in to_internal_value
    for field in fields:
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 354, in _writable_fields
    for field in self.fields.values():
  File "C:\Users\user1\Envs\projpy3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 348, in fields
    for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 1027, in get_fields
    field_names = self.get_field_names(declared_fields, info)
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 1128, in get_field_names
    serializer_class=self.__class__.__name__
AssertionError: The field 'participantIDs' was declared on serializer OrderSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.
```

I don't understand why that exception only occurs in the new version of the code, since I didn't change the `models`, `serializers`, or `views`, aside from the version updates.

this is what the problematic `serializer` looks like:

```py
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = ShortPersonSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)
    modified_by = ShortPersonSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)
    customer = OrderPersonSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True, partial=True)
    ...
    ...
    participantIDs = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, required=False, allow_null=True, slug_field='id', source='participants', queryset=Person.objects.all())
    ...
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'title','customer', 
                    'customer_copy_id', 'customer_copy_salutation', 'customer_copy_first_name', 'customer_copy_last_name', 'created_at', 'created_by', 'modified_at', 'modified_by')

     def create(self, validated_data):
        customer_data = validated_data.pop('customer', None)
        participants_data = validated_data.pop('participants', None)

        if customer_data and customer_data is not None:
            validated_data['customer'] = Person(pk=customer_data['id'])

        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)

        if participants_data and participants_data is not None:
            setattr(order, 'participants', participants_data)      # line 1
            order.save()                                           # line 2
...
```

**Additional info:**
Before this error was detected, I got a different error, with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  ...
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 204, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\user1\projects\proj_py3\orders\serializers.py", line 90, in create
    setattr(order, 'participants', participants_data)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Envs\projpy3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 509, in __set__
    % self._get_set_deprecation_msg_params(),
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use participants.set() instead.
```

so I had changed the `serializer` like this:

```py
...
...
        if participants_data and participants_data is not None:
            #setattr(order, 'participants', participants_data)      # line 1
            order.save()                                           # line 2
            order.participants.set(participants_data)
...
```

ever since I've done that, I get the `AssertionError` instead of the `TypeError`, and I don't know how to revert that problem. Ofcourse I changed the code back, but I've also deleted all the compiled files in the project directory, I deleted the virtual env and created a new one, I ran a disk cleanup on Windows, I even uninstalled Python37 in order to install it again. Always rebooting inbetween. All to no avail.

---

## UPDATE:

I compared the `update` and `create` methods in my project's `serializers.py` files with the ones in `rest_framework` version I'm using: [rest_framework/serializers.py on GitHub](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py)

I changed them according to the newer version of the Django REST framework (the code was developed for an older version).

I also checked all the `serializers` of the other Apps in the project, and I found out, that all but the concerned App `orders` had the `attribute` `participantsID` in their `Serializer`'s `Meta` class, in case it's supposed to access the other App through the other's `Serializer`.

In that case, it's like suggested in the comments: the `AssertionError` was there all along.

There is nothing else to do but to add the `attribute` to `fields`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **`participantIDs`** to your **`fields`** attribute of **`OrderSerializer`**'s `Meta` class

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # other code snippets
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (other-fields, 'participantIDs')
    # other code snippets
```

Comment: I don't think this is the right action, since the python 2 version of the code worked without that extra field. I also have a large database connected to the project, and I want to avoid unnecessary changes to its tables.
thanks a lot, anyway!

Comment: This solution is based on your given error traceback. I think it has nothing to do with the version Upgrade.

Comment: Whats the error? Add the error traceback to the question

Comment: Sorry, not "error". Let's call it a problem, that way it's easier to differentiate. I could simply add that field to solve this "symptomatically" for the time being, but I'd rather find the underlying cause of the inconsistency that I described. I will try different things and will update, if there's something worth mentioning. ty!

Comment: You upgraded a major language version *and* a major framework version.  Changes like this (the django error) are expected.  The DRF check regarding fields= vs declared fields has been there for quite while.  If you are *really* curious, then clone the repo and check the full history of serializers.py.  Nothing looks unusual here after so many upgrades.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I took over that project from someone else. Unfortunately, that person didn't provide me with a repository with any useful commits.